# why my question is marked with duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

why this question [why-excel-application-is-made-an-interface-rather-than-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084559/why-excel-application-is-made-an-interface-rather-than-a-class) is marked as duplicate and deleted.
I was told that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039064/please-explain-why-i-am-able-to-instantiate-the-application-interface-in-excel) is the duplicate but I edited the post to make clear it doesn't answer my question.
I tried comment and was told this "It needs to be used as plumbing for COM imported types", but I put this phrase in the question and said that I don't understand it and made clear I don't know about COM but the question is still deleted and marked with duplicate.
am I missing something ? if I'm right is there a way to undelete it (other than voting) ?

Comment: It looks like that question went thru many revisions and at least the title indicates something *very* different now than before.  When that happens, it takes time to get them reopened and so forth.  Right now, there are 2 votes to Undelete it.  You might refine it more to make clear what you are asking and how the other question is not a dupe.  The bigger lesson is to *labor* over the working and content and title of a question before you post.  The title is especially important because you want to catch the attention of people with knowledge in that area.

Comment: Actually, that question appears to have been "recycled".  Originally it was about jar files, now it is about Excel.

Comment: Your question basically comes down to "explain COM and the C# compiler to me". That's not going to happen without a specific, concrete question.

Comment: "PS:I know nothing about COM except that it's something that was used for some reason that I don't remember."  That got it zapped.

Answer (score 4):

You'd better ask a new question, than editing this one. This one has been closed and deleted, and trying to recycle it needs a lot of effort.

Just ask a new question. Make sure to search for duplicates next time, this one was very easy to find.

Comment: I can't ask a new question as I am question banned

Comment: @niceman: That is another issue. I know you have asked that already. I upvoted you on that question, so you might get out of it easier that way.